# Getting session variable manually with PHP and POST

Tags: javascript, php, session, post

I'm working with sessions in PHP and loading data to a page asynchronously with POST.

Normally, the PHPSESSID is created and saved as a cookie in the client's browser, and then when data is loaded with POST, the user's session ID is accessed by the script via the cookie.

However, for my users who are blocking cookies, when I am loading data to the page asynchronously with POST, I need to be able to retrieve their session data by looking their session ID manually.
First, I send the PHPSESSID to the page as a POST field, then I want to look up the user's session data on the server with the PHPSESSID that I sent to the page with POST.

For example

```
<?php

// Main Page

session_start(); 
$id = session_id(); // get session ID
$_SESSION["data"] = "example";
// User has cookies blocked, so no session cookie was sent. However, session ID will be sent using POST to the other page when it loads data asynchronously

?>

<script>


// Main page script

    const data = {
        sessionId: '<?php echo $id;?>'
    };

    const response = await fetch("/data.php", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        //make sure to serialize your JSON body
        body: JSON.stringify({
            data 
        })
    });

    const data = await response.text();

    console.log(data);



</script>

<?php

// Data.php


$data = utf8_encode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$data = json_decode($data)->data;
$sessionId = $data->sessionId;

// Now that I have the user's session ID, I want to get their session data. How can I use this ID to initialize the session?

// Would setting this session ID to the cookie work?

$_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"] = $sessionId;

// This works, but it's hacky and I'm wondering if there is a proper way to do this
session_start();

echo $_SESSION["data"];


?>
```

I have gotten as far as sending the user's PHPSESSID to the page with POST, but I don't know how to now use this ID to manually retrieve their session data from the server.

Comment: My initial experiment by setting $_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"] to the $sessionId value from post seems to work. Please let me know if there is a "proper" way to do this, since this seems pretty hacky

Comment: Yeah, if they are blocking cookies you need to pass the info data otherwise, for example by GET or POST. I would keep the "reserve solution" data separate from real sessions, just to remember they are separate ways of passing the session ID.